Make some macOS directories as external drive for USB connected device
How to share some macOs directories and make them external for USB connected device? For example I want to make my Mac recognise a flash USB drive when I connect it to my TV. I want to share some directory for this or I can make virtual drive for it.

Can you add some details about the setup you have in mind? Do you want to plug in an USB drive into a TV and then access the drive from your Mac via the TV? Or do you want to expose a directory on your Mac so the TV can access files stored in it?

You can have music and video files on an external drive connected to your Mac and set up the "Music" and "TV" apps to access videos and movies from the external drive. Can't do that with audio books, and not with photos. Can't quite see why you want to connect a USB device to your TV.
